# Oracle round negative decimal_places?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

as we know and [explained here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/round_nbr.php)  The oracle `ROUND` function will round number 
up or down and i can choose how many digits after the , i want to use, but 
I saw a function that has a `ROUND` as below

**Example:**

```
select round(125.11,-1) from dual;
```

what the minus one means ?? what it dose here ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions155.htm#SQLRF00698):

> ROUND returns n rounded to integer places to the right of the decimal point. If you omit integer, then n is rounded to zero places. **If integer is negative, then n is rounded off to the left of the decimal point.**

So:

- `round(n, 0)` rounds `n` to the nearest unit
- `round(n, 1)` rounds `n` to the nearest tenth
- `round(n, -1)` rounds `n` to the nearest ten
- `round(n, 2)` rounds `n` to the nearest hundredth
- `round(n, -2)` rounds `n` to the nearest hundred

etc